# SSH via HTTP proxy with password on Windows with mingw64

Tags: ssh, proxy, mingw, http-proxy

I use Portable Git x64 on Windows. I run everything thought Git Bash. I need to ssh to a server which is reachable only via HTTP proxy. Authentication for server is via pubkey, authentication for proxy is via password, usernames are different. My `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host server
  Hostname server_hostname
  User server_username
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  ProxyCommand /c/PortableGit/mingw64/bin/connect.exe -H proxy_username@proxy_ip:12345 %h %p
```

The problem starts when ssh tries to pop-up the window where you need to enter a password for the HTTP proxy, log from `ssh -vvv server`:

```
$ ssh -vvv server
OpenSSH_7.9p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1a  20 Nov 2018
debug1: Reading configuration data /c/Users/username/.ssh/config
debug1: /c/Users/username/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for server
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec /c/PortableGit/mingw64/bin/connect.exe -H proxy_username@proxy_ip:12345 server_hostname 22
debug1: identity file /c/Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /c/Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.9
'C:\PortableGit\mingw64\libexec\git-core\git-gui--askpass' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
FATAL: Cannot decide password for proxy authentication.ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

`git-gui--askpass` is there, but for some reason it's not picked up by ssh. Running `file 'C:\PortableGit\mingw64\libexec\git-core\git-gui--askpass'` gives:

```
$ file 'C:\PortableGit\mingw64\libexec\git-core\git-gui--askpass'
C:\PortableGit\mingw64\libexec\git-core\git-gui--askpass: POSIX shell script, ASCII text executable
```

Content of the `git-gui--askpass` is identical to https://github.com/git/git/blob/3bab5d56259722843359702bc27111475437ad2a/git-gui/git-gui--askpass

I tried to run this script via command line, it works fine:

[image]

Also, I tried to specify another program as `SSH_ASKPASS=/mingw64/libexec/git-core/git-askpass.exe` (which I assume a stupid thing to do). This does not work either:

```
...
fatal: failed to acquire credentials.
```

I tried to supply a password in `~/.ssh/config` as:

```
ProxyCommand /c/PortableGit/mingw64/bin/connect.exe -H proxy_username:proxy_password@proxy_ip:12345 %h %p
                                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

but this is ignored by ssh.

Besides, I tried to connect via MobaXterm and this works completely fine -- I've been asked for a proxy password and after entering it I am connected. Also, after connecting in MobaXterm I can connect in command line since the proxy does not ask for a password for some time. But for a different reason I cannot use MobaXterm.

Any ideas on how to make it work?

Comment: Why do you say it is ignored if it is in the log Executing proxy command?

Comment: What do you mean by "it is in the log Executing proxy command"? If I specify the password for proxy in .ssh/config it's ignored by ssh, in the log there is nothing about the password, ssh tries to pop-up the window for password and fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utility connect.exe works with HTTP_PROXY_USER and HTTP_PROXY_PASSWORD environment variables. Solution found in [source code](https://github.com/brunoborges/ssh-over-http-proxy/blob/ad78a52ba13ed6775e9d8fef6689b2afbc9db67d/connect.c#L420)

Comment: thanks much, that worked! Also, reference to source code is very much appreciated, I was able to identify another problem I had!

Answer (score 0):

Try keeping your password in your `~/.ssh/config` file and add

```
unset SSH_ASKPASS
```

To your .bashprofile

Comment: Tried your suggestion today. Basically nothing happens in this case, it hangs up at the moment when it needs to ask for a proxy pass, I assume ignores the password from config.
I ended up using putty, there is an option to specify a password for a proxy..